# Assign Azure Powershell variable to DevOps Pipeline variable

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can I assigned the $NewIP variable precalculated in this step to a DevOps pipeline variable called $pipeline_ip?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you. Do you want to create azure devops variable `$pipeline_ip` with powershell variable `$NewIP` or the other way?

Comment: $pipeline_ip is created in a varaiable group in DevOps. To this variable I want to assign the newly created withtin the run $NewIP.

Comment: why the downvote? I hade my research and couldn't find the specific info, the topic seems to be useful as the answer was upvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#logging-command-format) command if you want to assign powershell variable to Azure DevOps variable

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pipeline_ip;]$NewIP"
```

**Update after clarification:**

If you use syntax like:

`$NewIP = $(pipeline_ip)`
Then `$(pipeline_ip)` would be replaced with the value before script will be executed.

And if you use syntax like

`$NewIP = $env:PIPELINE_IP` 
then you will refer to environment variable and since all DevOps variables are mapped (except secret variables - here you need to express this excplicitly) it would also work.

However, these are two ways of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two methods:

1. $NewIP = $(pipeline_ip) [Macro syntax variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#macro-syntax-variables)
2. $NewIP = $env:PIPELINE_IP [Set variables in pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline)